# How I could add some MP3 files from android storage to streaming asset folder at run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to get some MP3 files from user and play it in run time.
Is there any way to get it from android storage and put it in streaming asset folder to play it?

Comment: Almost certainly - if its stored as mp3 and you can get them to pick it, you should be able to upload it to where you are streaming from

Comment: I can not get them to pick it

Comment: well then you will need to write code to go find them

Comment: I need exactly the code which could for example import some .mp3 files from Storage/Music to "Application.persistentDataPath".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

> Application.persistentDataPath

which points to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<< packagename >>/files on Android. After you find the path, load the file through WWW class

```
 WWW www = new WWW("file://" + path);
 yield www;
```

Once you have the file in the application, assign it to sound component and play.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i need to first read from Storage/Music and write it to" Application.persistentDataPath".

Answer (score 0):

```
public const string audioName = "mario.wav";
[Header("Audio Stuff")]
public AudioSource audioSource;
public AudioClip audioClip;
public string soundPath;

private void Awake()
{
    audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    soundPath = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Sound/";

    StartCoroutine(LoadAudio());
}

private IEnumerator LoadAudio()
{
    WWW request = GetAudioFromFile(soundPath, audioName);
    yield return request;

    audioClip = request.GetAudioClip();
    audioClip.name = audioName;
    // BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    // FileStream stream = new FileStream(, FileMode.Create);
    // bin.Serialize(stream, audioClip.ToString());
    // stream.Close();
    PlayAudioFile();
}

private void PlayAudioFile()
{
    audioSource.clip = audioClip;
    //audioSource.Play();
    audioSource.loop = true;
}

private WWW GetAudioFromFile(string path, string filename)
{
    string audioToLoad = string.Format(path + "{0}", filename);
    WWW request = new WWW(audioToLoad);
    return request;
}
```